# How to quickly rename files on NAS

Tags: terminal, nas, macos

I have recently added a Qnap (Linux) NAS to my Mac OS environment, as the main file server.

I realized many of the Mac OS files have `/` characters, that do not behave well in Linux, as they disappear when seen from Macs (they actually are being renamed in Linux and becoming invisible from the Macs... dunno why).

Example: a file named `image/b.jpg` should be renamed as `image_b.jpg` to avoid problems on the Qnap Linux NAS.

Anyway, I'd like to build a script from Mac OS Terminal to access the Linux NAS and perform a "search and change" of the `/` character to something else like: `_`.

I have begun by writing this:

```
ssh admin@192.168.2.2
for f in $(find /share/Public/ -name "*:*"); do mv $f ${f/:/_}; done
```

I can log on the remote NAS, but seems not to work... I am not a tech guy, and tried to collect some code samples from the internet.

What are options to automate or script file renames for a NAS share?

Comment: Could you provide an example of how a filename looks like in macOS and Linux ? And in which directory or directories does it happen? Also, let us know if those files are visible in Finder. Please update the question once you have an answers for us.

Comment: Also, please be more specific about the "but seems not to work": what happens if you run the command?

Comment: How do you see the / in mac file names. I thought macOS hid that from all the user viewable information

Comment: How do you know that `image/b.jpg` is a filename to begin with ? It means, `b.jpg` is located inside `image` folder. Please, post an example output of `ls -lai`. Also, please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename

Comment: The `/` in filenames on macOS is a HFS legacy, you can include them in filenames when renaming in Finder. In Terminal the filename will include a `:` instead of the `/`, the conversion is handled transparently by Finder (or whatever library call it uses).

Comment: @nohillside Quite fascinating indeed! So, I just tried, `touch ':foobar'` will create a filename as `/foobar` in finder. But, in terminal it will show as: `:foobar`. Very interesting. So, OP or anyone should avoid naming files with forward slashes in it, to avoid this conversion, right?

Comment: @RakibFiha That seems to be the reason why they want to convert the names. It's a pity the OP hasn't come back to provide clarifications though.

Answer (score 1):

Running `for` over the results of a `find` is not recommended, it will break on filenames with spaces, newlines etc.

You can use the following instead once you are logged into your NAS:

```
find /share/Public/ -depth -name '*:*' -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1//:/_}"' _ {} \;
```

To be on the save side, run

```
find /share/Public/ -depth -name '*:*' -exec sh -c 'echo mv -- "$1" "${1//:/_}"' _ {} \;
```

and check the output for anything unexpected.

PS: The duplicated `//` in `${1//:/_}` is intentional to ensure that all occurrences of `:` are replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can do this right from the [Finder](https://tidbits.com/2018/06/28/macos-hidden-treasures-batch-rename-items-in-the-finder/).

You can also use [Automator](https://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-mac-os-x/) to do so.

If that's not your thing, there are a few different tools that are available (yes, I'm aware you can write a *NIX script to do so). [A Better Finder Rename](https://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/) is one.

Comment: From my understanding, OP wants to rename files over ssh. How can OP mount those files in Finder ?

Comment: He says he's added it as a file server to his environment. Unless OP says otherwise, I'm assuming that a file server is visible in Finder. It'd be really weird if it wasn't.

Comment: There is some filename conversion between `/` and `:` at work here, not sure how well renaming from the macOS side of things actually works.

Comment: Is there some evidence that renaming files on a network share from MacOS on whatever version the OP is on, is not recommended, or is known not to work? I think we have to assume it does work unless there's evidence otherwise.

Comment: Renaming does work. As a matter of fact many files containing "/" when moved on Linux NAS, apparently disappear. I think they're renamed by Linux to conform to its naming standard, thus becoming invisible when seen from a Mac OS machine. I discovered that by accessing these files from the NAS...